# Firebase How To Save Auto ID to also be in field id Upon Creating Document?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

So basically when I create a post it is saved in Firebase with some random big id. Which is the way I want it and its fine. I just also want upon creation that that same auto-generated id isnt just a document id but also I want it automatically copied to a field id inside collection posts. So basically upon creation I want to have 2 SAME ids, one being automatically created documents id and other directly right away coping to a field "id". Any help?

```
addPost = async ({ text, avatar, name,  }) => {

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      this.firestore
        .collection("posts")
        .add({
          text,
          text2,
          //I want "id" here that would equal not yet created auto id
          uid: this.uid,
          timestamp: this.timestamp,
          avatar,
          name,
        })
        .then((ref) => {
          res(ref);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          rej(error);
        });
    });
  };
```

Comment: Easiest solution might be to simply `add(...)` a blank document, then in the `.then(ref){...}` section, update the blank document with all your stuff. Or, do the approach you are doing, but in the `.then(ref)` section, simply update the ref with `ref.update({uid:ref.id})`

Comment: Instead of using `add()`, call `doc()` to generate a document reference with a random ID, then use that ID in a call to `set()`.

Comment: @Snowmonkey can u write it? idk how u meant I should write this>?

Comment: oh it works. f amazing. thank u!